# C# access variable from another class without reconstructing the class

Tags: c#, class

How can I access a variable from another class without reconstructing it?

Class #1:

```
namespace Server.world
{
    public class WorldData
    {
        private entitys.Player[] Players = new entitys.Player[Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxplayers"])];

        public entitys.Player this[int i]
        {
            get { return Players[i]; }
            set { Players[i] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Class #2: constructing the `worldData` class:

```
namespace Server
{
    class StartUp
    {
        public Server.tcpserver.TcpServer ListenerTcp = new Server.tcpserver.TcpServer();
        public world.WorldData WorldData = new world.WorldData();

        /// <summary>
        /// Server start function
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            string rootFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootfolder"];

            if (!Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rootFolder);
                string pathString = Path.Combine(rootFolder, "world");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
            }

            ListenerTcp.StartListening();
            //No code below this point
        }
    }
}
```

Class #3:

```
namespace Server.tcpserver
{
    class TcpServer
    {
        int counter = 0;

        public void StartListening()
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

            serverSocket.Start();
            counter = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                counter += 1;

                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                Server.client.Client Client = new Server.client.Client(clientSocket);
                Console.WriteLine("Player Connected!");
                //get world playerdata here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I do this? I've looked everywhere but couldn't find it

Comment: Where do you instantiate class 3?  You could pass in your `WorldData` object in the constructor.  You could instantiate it inside your class 3

Comment: How are class `StartUp` and `Class3` related to each other?

Comment: you can access members without instatiation only by converting the class to be "static"

Comment: You need to get a copy of CLR Via C# and read it.  There's no way you're going to get your copypasted code to work if you can't even figure this out :(

Comment: @Will Copypasted code? I beg your pardon?

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry forgot to add one file hang on

Comment: Yeah, sure, you wrote this code without any knowledge of how basic fundamentals of object oriented programming work.

Comment: @Will Oh well I guess my experiance with php doesn't count then?

Comment: @Will Oh and Don't forget my experiance with c# oop I just never had the need to acces an array from another class without constructing it ;)

Comment: PHP?  No, that doesn't count.  We're talking about the-first-week-of-the-first-year-of-programming-school basic.  Instance vs. static, when and why to use one or the other, and how to handle situations like this.  Seriously, grab CLR Via C# and skip the first chapter.  You'll thank me.

Comment: @Will Hmm I'll take a look at it, my way of learning is typing code until you get an error if I can't fix google said error :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, you could provide a constructor that takes the instance of `WorldData` or  even the `StartUp` instance which exposes the `WorldData` as property.

```
public class TcpServer
{
    int counter = 0;
    private StartUp startUp:

    public TcpServer(StartUp startUp)
    {
        this.startUp = startUp;
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        // ...
        var worldData = this.startUp.WorldData;     // <--- !!!
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now i would also use the constructor of `StartUp` to initialize the `TcpServer`:

```
public class StartUp
{
    public StartUp()
    {
        WorldData = new world.WorldData();
        ListenerTcp = new Server.tcpserver.TcpServer( this );  // <--- !!!
    }

    public Server.tcpserver.TcpServer ListenerTcp;
    public world.WorldData WorldData;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like a clean solution, but what about making the class containing the array static?

Comment: @StijnBernards: why would you want to do that? Do you want to support only a single world? A static class can only contain static  members which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: Well I want 1 worldData class wich contains all player data and multiple Levelclasses. I'm using the WorldData class like uhh... Well a file where I keep all public variable that other classes need to edit.